# pillow cleaning machine

Tags: us3081553

My father invented this product and I would like to know if it ever went into production and if so who produced it. Is the patent still in effect. Could I use this patent to produce the machine or sell the patent to a company?

Answer (score 1):

It would have expired in 1980 so there are no right associated with it. You, or anyone else, do not need **any** patent to produce **any machine**. It is the patent's of others that one must avoid when making this or any other product.